# Value Lists in MS Access 2007

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have a database in Access 2007 that maintains staff records. Amongst other things it is used to record ethnic origins for Equality purposes. Latest advice on this subject lists 63 possible answers to the question "What is your ethnic origin?". Until now I have been recording data in a Text field, which uses a Combo Box and Value list with only 17 possible answers. Users are not allowed to change the list.

A Value List with 63 items strikes me as cumbersome, although I'm sure it will work.

Does anyone have any suggestions for a 'slicker' approach?

Answer (score 2):

I have decided to create a separate table. Latest advice contains groups of ethnic origins, and each ethnic origin has a code, e.g. "(A)". So I now have a table with fields: Group; Ethnicity;Code.